# VSTS query by WIQL does not return requested fields

Tags: javascript, azure-devops, visual-studio-extensions, wiql

I'm building a Widget in VSTS and I'm calling the queryByWiql() method from Work Item Tracking rest client.

The query I have is:

```
queryString = {
    "query": "Select [Microsoft.VSTS.Scheduling.RemainingWork]
     From WorkItems
     Where [System.WorkItemType] = 'Task'
     AND [System.State] <> 'Done'
     order by [System.CreatedDate] desc"
};
```

But the result looks like this, where none of the work item actually contain the Remaining Work Information:

[image]

This is true for any fields I request; Title, State, Assigned To etc.
The fields I've requested will appear under columns. But none of the work items themvselves will have the information.

Why is this the case? And how can I fix it? Cheers

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is an expected behavior. Currently, there is no way to call the API to return the detailed work item information from a WIQL query directly. You need to get these information in two steps:

1. Get the ID of the work items from a WIQL which you have done.
2. Get these work items via [Get a list of work items by ID](https://www.visualstudio.com/docs/integrate/api/wit/work-items#by-ids). And you can [specify the field to get](https://www.visualstudio.com/docs/integrate/api/wit/work-items#with-specific-fields) at this step.

Instruction on [WIQL Query](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/integrate/api/wit/wiql#get-work-items) page:

> After executing a query, [get the work items using the IDs](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/integrate/api/wit/work-items#byids) that
>   are returned in the query results response. You can get up to 200 work
>   items at a time.

Comment: "This is expected behaviour", and yet there is no mention of this anywhere on your page here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/vsts/wit/wiql/query%20by%20wiql?view=vsts-rest-4.1

_In fact_, it states in part 2 that it's possible to send a query of some sort and get the data back from the query, but there's no mention of the POST body needed to do this!